# How do you clone an entire backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have a large backbone model that is fairly complex and contains nested arrays and objects.

If I clone using the backbone method, like this:

```
 var model2 = model1.clone();
```

It will clone the top-level properties and arrays, but anything deeper, is not cloned at all.

For example, it will clone these model properties just fine:

id: 29832,
title: ExtremeGaming,
type: "9a",
users: [0: "advanced", 1: "elite"]

But more complex properties are ignored, like this(this is what I see in `console.log`.  In backbone, the model is games.:

```
games: 
   adventure: 
      models: Array(1)
          0: child
             attributes:
                 title: "PitFall"
                 year: "(old) 1981"
```

Is there a backbone way of cloning the entire backbone model?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by deeper? can you provide an example of the model structure that you want to clone? and what properties is not cloning?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim It seems nested models are ignored. I added an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Backbone crew discourage storing anything other than primitives in models, and therefore if you're going to do so, it's on you to handle it.

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3457

One can use the `lodash` [cloneDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) function for this, e.g.,

```
const model2 = new Model(_.cloneDeep(model1.attributes));
```

There are several alternatives to `cloneDeep()`; depending on your supporting library cast of characters, there may be a work-alike already available to you. For example, babel and core-js as of late have the usual auto-polyfill support for `structuredClone()`, so if you're already set up for that, it'd be my first choice now.

Answer (score 2):

backbone is cloning by creating new instance with a copy of the attributes, so as long as the property is on the attribute, it should be safe to be cloned

from backbone source code

```
// Create a new model with identical attributes to this one.
clone: function() {
   return new this.constructor(this.attributes);
},
```